Como resolver Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open vite.config.js
Estoy teniendo un problema al hacer npm run dev me da el siguiente error
failed to load config from C:\Users\rober\Documents\GitHub\SPHere-FrontEnd-React\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\rober\Documents\GitHub\SPHere-FrontEnd-React\vite.config.js.timestamp-1716474665024-cb2def9165217.mjs'

antes no me dejaba ni instalar el node_modules porque se quedaba pillado en idealTree pero al final mirando soluciones decidi downgradear la version node a la 18 y me funciono pero luego me daba el siguinte fallo y ayer me funcionaba bien y ha sido esta mañana al intentar ejecutarlo cuando me ha dado el error, ya he probado a desactivar la ipv6 de windows, a borrar el package.lock.json y node_modules y volver a instalar pero me da el mismo fallo. Es como que se crean archivos temporales e intenta buscarlo, si le cambio el nombre al archivo y le pongo el temporal que estaba buscando ya no da el fallo pero no funciona la aplicación, ya no se que mas hacer si alguien sabria como arreglarlo agradecería su ayuda. También he intentado cambiar la extensión del archivo de .js a .mjs y nada.
Otra cosa que he intentado es instalar vite 4.2.2 y su plugin de react en la versión 1.0.0 y no ha funcionado.
Si le cambio el nombre al archivo por el que intneta buscar me sale este error
Re-optimizing dependencies because lockfile has changed
error when starting dev server:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\rober\Documents\GitHub\SPHere-FrontEnd-React\node_modules\.vite\deps\@reduxjs_toolkit.js'

, aun así aunque arregle este error no creo que funcione, el que quiero arreglar es el de ENOENT.
He conseguido arreglar el último error borrando la carpeta .vite y ya parece que se ejecuta en localhost pero se queda cargando infinatemente y no hace nada.

El error reside en que el archivo -timestamp.mjs no existe e intenta cargar la configuración de un archivo que no existe en vez de cargarla desde vite.config.js
He probado a crear un nuevo proyecto desde 0 y copiar los archivos y al ejecutar npm run dev me da el mismo error asi que no es cosa del proyecto
